# Nodejs recommended clean folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, architecture

I'm planning a medium-sized node project because I have a java background, `grade` did everything for me regarding the general structure of the project. And as far as i already know, the MVC pattern is not very common in Node projects.
Now i am wondering how i can structure my project.

I already have some files:
Server-related:
-server.js just the app.listen(port, callback) function
-app.js in here are all expressjs settings like app.use(xyz)

client-related:
my public files index.html, index.css and some client side javascript

And some business logic:
my project does some heavy calculations on the server side and just displays the results in the index.html, so my business logic contains the most files.
For example: a `PriorityQueue.js` File, that is just a library class for a PriorityQueue Implementation.
Furthermore I have implemented some other Data structures and Algorithms.

I do not have many routes, just /error and /home

My Questions is now: How do i structure all these files, to have a clean and beautiful project structure?
I already read the AirBnB and the Google JS Style Guide, but they don't say anything about the project structure.

Your help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: It's entirely up to you. Work with whatever makes you happy.

Answer (score 0):

I generally create a `server.js` main file and  `routes/`, `controllers/` and `services/` and `models/` subdirectories. If I have a "files" service I will then create `files.route.js`, `files.controller.js`, `files.service.js` and `files.model.js`.